# Why is my hash / salt technique for storing passwords not working?

Tags: php, hash, mysqli, salt

I am trying to make a safe, custom, user login system, but it currently does not work.  The idea is to create a user with a safe, encrypted password. However, when using the correct password, it does not log on to the site.

Output when using the password `123456789jp`:

`$6$j7Rd68RhKNx.6ccH$9lvRDdks.jx4hk7.YQ0hpvzPE22h/BZQ/9yXiwTMBV1Kx2xr2gbIZZJxYjeLrA41nL2WGjmt.FMQi877uOXrP1`

Relevant function:

```
// function register_user()
function bruger_opret_siden(){
            if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT NULL FROM `bruger` WHERE `brugernavn` = ?'))
            {
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $brugernavn);
                $brugernavn = $_POST["brugernavn"];
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->store_result();
                $count = $stmt->num_rows;
                $stmt->close();
                if($count > 0)
                {
                    $user_found = 1;
                }
            }
            if(!isset($user_found))
            {
                //Check if the user exists.

                if(!isset($errors))
                {
                    $pb = null;

                    include 'function/class.upload.php';
                    $handle = new Upload($_FILES["file"]);

                    if($handle->uploaded)
                    {
                        //trims to next request         
                    }

                 $password = $_POST["pass"];
                 $algorithm = '$6$'; //<--- This means the SHA 512
                 $salt = $this->generateSalt(16); //<--- SHA 512 uses a 16-character salt

                 $hash = crypt($password, $algorithm . $salt);

                if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO `bruger` 
                (`rank`, `email`, `brugernavn`, `password`, `profilbillede`, `profilbillede_godkendt`, `navn`, `efternavn`, `alder_d`, `alder_m`, `alder_aar`, `status`, `kon`, `seksualitet`, `land_by`, `hojde`) 
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'))
                {

                    $stmt->bind_param('issssisssssiiisi', $rank, $email, $brugernavn, $password, $profilbillede, $pb_godkendt, $navn, $efternavn, $alder_d, $alder_m, $alder_aar, $kon, $seksualitet, $partnerstatus, $land_by, $hojde);
                    $rank = '1';
                    $pb_godkendt = '1';
                    $email = $_POST["email"];
                    $brugernavn = $_POST["brugernavn"];//C
                    $password = $hash;//C
                    $profilbillede = $pb;//C
                    $navn = $_POST["navn"];
                    $efternavn = $_POST["efternavn"];
                    $alder_d = $_POST["alder_d"];
                    $alder_m = $_POST["alder_m"];
                    $alder_aar = $_POST["alder_aar"];
                    $kon = $_POST["kon"];
                    $seksualitet = $_POST["seksualitet"];
                    $partnerstatus = $_POST["partnerstatus"];
                    $land_by = $_POST["land_by"];
                    $hojde = $_POST["hojde"];

                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();

                    echo "ok";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // There was an error 
                        echo 'error: ' . $mysqli->error;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<li id=\"check_not\">Dette brugernavn er optaget!!</li>";
            }
    }
```

Code to make a hash from the password and a salt to register the user:

```
function generateSalt($length) {
         $alphabet = './ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
         $alphabet_length = strlen($alphabet);
         $salt = '';
         for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
             $salt .= $alphabet[rand(0, $alphabet_length - 1)];
         }
         return $salt;
     }
```

Two functions to show users information.

```
$pass = $mebe->generateSalt();
                $users = $mebe->bruger_opret_siden();
```

The following function contains the problem; it does not log the user in.  While there are no errors produced, it doesn't work.

```
function godkendt_login()
    {
        if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT `id`, `brugernavn`, `rank`, `profilbillede`, `profilbillede_godkendt` FROM `bruger` WHERE `brugernavn` = ? AND `password` = ?"))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $brugernavn, $password);
            $brugernavn = $_POST["brugernavn"];
            $password = sha1($_POST["pass"]);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($id, $brugernavn, $rank, $profilbillede, $profilbillede_godkendt);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $count = $stmt->num_rows;
            $stmt->close();

            if($count > 0)
            {
                $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true;
                $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                $_SESSION["profilbillede"] = $profilbillede;
                $_SESSION["brugernavn"] = $brugernavn;
                $_SESSION["rank"] = $rank;
                $_SESSION["profilbillede_godkendt"] = $profilbillede_godkendt;

                if($_SESSION["logged_in"] == true)
                {
                    echo "ok";
                }
                else
                {
                    // Sorry, please try again.
                                    echo "Desværre prøve igen."
                }
            }
            else
            {
                          echo "Skrive et password eller brugernavn"
            }
        }
    }
```

Log file / inc file:

```
<?php
    /*
     * // Grant the administrative privilige to show the content.
     * Giver admin adgang til se indhold på siden.
     */
    if(isset($_SESSION["rank"]) && $_SESSION["rank"] > 0) {
        $bruger = $mebe->brugerindhold_side();
    }


    /*
     * // Grant normal access to the page.
     * Hvis ingen af dem så få de bare adgang sådan her..
     */
    else{
    ?>
<form name="login" method="post" action="#">
    <h1>Log ind</h1>
    <p>Brugernavn</p><input type="text" name="brugernavn"/>
    <p>Password</p><input type="password" name="pass"/>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="Log_ind" value="Log ind" id="login">
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["Log_ind"]))
    {
    $login = $mebe->godkendt_login();
    }
    ?>
</form>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, given that I cannot fully grasp your code due to a language difference.
A salt should be a reproducible value. From what I gather yours seems to be generated @ random.

If so, the hashes won't add up, therefore the check fails.
Use a constant value for the hash and **do not store it in a database**!

For example:

```
<?php

     function generateHash($in)
     {
         $salt = "Th1s1sAS4lt";
         return md5(sha1($in) . $salt);
     }
?>
```

Also, any post value should be checked because it is inputted by a user and may contain illegal characters or harmful code. Observe the following:

```
<?php
    // Note that the input contains SQL.
    // bemærke, at de input indeholder SQL.                 
    $_POST['passwd'] = "'p@ssword' OR 'a' = 'a'";

    if (tilmeld_dig())
    {
        // Log the user in.
        // brugeren er logget på
    }


    function tilmeld_dig()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT brugernavn from tbl_brugere WHERE adgangskode = " . $_POST['passwd'];

            // Execute the database command. 
        $res// = Database kommando udføre
        if ($res)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
?>
```

In the example above, the user is logged in no matter the password, because there is an SQL command injected that will **always** be true.

Though this is a crude example, please review this:
http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=nl&sl=en&tl=da&prev=_dd&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.unixwiz.net%2Ftechtips%2Fsql-injection.html

I tried to support you with some Danish comment because this is important in security systems. You're on the right track but I recommend you to take a look at my suggestion.

Also, this is untested code, but more or less how it works.

Comment: Is your problem solved now? This appeared to be **a** problem with the code, though I'm not sure it resolved your question.

Comment: Also, I do suspect you of guarding information about alien life, because that is one hell of a password! ;)

Comment: It's loose now :) I strap just like this;
`$password = sha1('ri629' . $_POST["pass"] . 'h1ry6328');`

Comment: Okay, are you using the post value directly? Because that leaves a big hole in security. I would recommend processing the posted value, checking it for a correct value before you use it.

Comment: I do not understand just quite what you mean by that?

Comment: Please let me know if the Danish is correct, I used Google translate for it ;)

Comment: Well, at least you take the time to try, that's good. I'll edit your post to correct the English.

Comment: Aaah :) has du en mail so we can ever write together or what?

Comment: Can not finde its email... :(

Comment: Actually a salt _should_ be random, and it _should_ be stored in the database together with the hash-value. Thought this information is necessary, should somebody stumble over this old thread.

Comment: Multiple opinions may exist, however... salts are intended to spoil attempts of reverting hashes Given that some hacker steals your password hashes, those become public. However, the salt remains private since it is embedded in your code. Thus adding to security. Agreed, it is my opinion, but I believe it to be well-founded and it is certainly based on experience.